# port unification with persistent channel

Tags: netty

I am trying to adapt the Port Unification example to my codebase.  The issue I think I'm having is that a channel is kept open between the client & server until either the server shuts down or the client is finished its task, or, more specifically, the same pipeline is used the entire time.  So the workflow in the example where the unifier handler is removed from the pipeline does not work.

The issue I was seeing with the Port Unification example as-is was that my client kept pre-pending the magic bytes to each request, but the server side channel removed the port unification handler the first request that came in once the message was determined to be a valid protocol message.  Subsequent messages over the channel, which contained the prefix magic bytes from the client, were not able to be processed because the unification handler was no longer in the pipeline to consume the magic bytes resulting in the messages being malformed.

I was able to get around this by leaving the unification handler in the pipeline, but then, each time the sniffer identified the protocol, it was adding protocol handlers.  Since the pipeline was persistent for the life of the channel, I kept adding the same handlers over and over again.  This was easy enough to workaround by adding an attribute to the channel to avoid re-adding stuff to the pipeline.

Now the issue I'm seeing is for messages broken up into several buffers.  If the client sends 2k bytes broken into two messages.  The first message is correctly sniffed and passed onto the next handler (LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder, to be specific).  It does not have all the bytes, so it waits for the rest.  When the next message comes in with the rest of the bytes, because i cannot remove the unifier from the pipeline, I sniff again, and the sniff fails.

Is there a workaround for this, or a better way to accomplish the same thing?

UPDATE:

Moving the consumption of the magic bytes out of the unifier seems like the right approach, but what still continues to be the issue (or seems to be) is that dynamically altering the pipeline does not work the same in netty 4 as it does in netty 3.

my client protocol is prepending all requests w/ a byte sequence to identify it.  with netty 3, we simply skipped over the bytes in the ChannelBuffer, removed the unifier and added the appropriate protocol handling to service that request.  the same thing happened on all subsequent requests and it worked perfectly.

however, with netty 4, once we've removed the handler from the pipeline that eats the magic bytes, its gone for the lifetime of the Channel, which persists until the client closes it.  so before it seemed like the pipeline/ChannelHandlerContext was new for each message going through the channel, it's re-used each time and i think this is where the problem is.

afaict, this makes this type of dynamic changing of the pipeline difficult or impossible in practice.  i want something to consume only the first N bytes of each request, but i can't leave it in the pipeline because large requests broken into several ByteBuf's will all have their first N bytes eaten, which badly breaks things.

Update 2:  I think the behavior I'm now seeing is related to what I've mentioned in a followup topic:  [how to manage a prefixed byte sequence which identifies your protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454206/how-to-manage-a-prefixed-byte-sequence-which-identifies-your-protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port unification example does not expect the client to switch protocol. If you really want to support that, you have to come up with a mechanism for the client to say: "I'm done using this specific protocol for now, next message may use a different protocol", and then have the PortUnificationServerHandler re-inserted in a cleared pipeline.

UPDATE:

After reading the scenario again, I think your problem is that your unification handler is consuming the "magic bytes". It shouldn't. The Netty example doesn't. The unifictaion handler should just determine the protocol, install the corrcet handler sequence and get out. The new handler sequence should see the first byte buffer unchanged, i.e. no bytes should've been consumed.

Comment: the client is not switching protocols.  it's simply sending a second message over the channel.  its an async RPC client-server.  the first RPC exchange b/w the two is fine, the second is a failure either because the unifier is not in the pipeline, or if it is, the second request is large enough that it's broken into several ByteBuf's

Comment: I should point out, that the exact same setup in 3.6.6 worked fine.  all ive done is migrate the codebase to netty 4

Comment: @Michael Ok, but that's how I interpreted the scenario.

Comment: that's cool, i just wanted to clarify.  what i need is the ability for the unifier handler to only get called once *per read*; when the message from the client is broken up into multiple ByteBuf's that's when there are problems.  the original example just removes the unifier which gets around this, but you can't do that if you plan on re-using the channel.  my use case does not seem that unusual, so its hard to believe that the netty folks don't have a solution for this situation

Comment: Your suggestion that the unifier doesnt remove the magic bytes makes sense, an error on my part.  But something has to remove those bytes, and I don't understand how it can be done when the request is broken across several ByteBuf's.  having a handler that would eat the two bytes is easy, but having it eat only the initial two bytes seems tricky.

Comment: Suggestion: First make a handler  that can read and process one of your protocols. Aggregating split messages should be easy if you have a properly framed protocol. When that works, incorporate it in a unification handler.

Comment: I currently only have one protocol, and 20k LOC of code that worked w/ netty 3.x, and has done so for 2+ years.   I'm trying to port it to use Netty 4 and its clear that how the unification handler used to work is not compatible with how it works in Netty 4.  I *think* that's due to lifecycle changes in Channel & ChannelHandlerContext; previously i think a new pipeline was constructed for each message exchange, now it seems like there's only one for the lifetime of the channel.  which makes dynamic modifications much harder