# how to manage a prefixed byte sequence which identifies your protocol

Tags: netty

This is related to my question regarding the unification setup ([port unification with persistent channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445861/port-unification-with-persistent-channel))

I am attempting to send a two byte sequence prefixed to all traffic for my protocol; I am doing this so there is something to sniff in the unification handler when i update to support more than one protocol.

On the client, i have a simple outbound handler at the end of the pipeline that prefixes the ByteBuf with the two protocol identifying bytes, and a simple inbound handler in the front of the server pipeline which will extract them.  I've managed to get this working for small messages.

The subsequent handler in the server queue is a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` which I'm using to frame in the incoming traffic (protobuf objects).  What appears to be happening is the client sends a large request, say 5M.  I get a series of 64k buffers that come through the server pipeline, the last one of which passes over the threshold the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` is waiting for, it extracts the frame and passes it on for handling -- this happens correctly.

At this point, everything breaks.  From what I can tell, the last 64k buffer from the client contained the rest of the data for the frame, the 2 byte sequence signaling the start of the next request, and then some more content.  I think this data is sitting in the frame decoder, which now will use the two protocol magic bytes as the length of the next frame, which is incorrect, and things break down from there.

The `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` looks like it would work in this case since that two byte sequence will break apart each logical frame/request, but that seems like overkill in this scenario.

Is there some other decoder that would work in this case, or should I stick with the `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look through the documentation for [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) there is a great example of how to do just what you are trying to do.  The fourth example has a fixed width header in front of the length field, and it configures the FrameDecoder not to strip any of the header info.

**EDIT**

For your server, the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder should come first, then your handler that checks the header can remove the header and length fields and pass the data on accordingly.

On the client side, you can use a [LengthFieldPrepender](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html), then add an additional handler after that to prepend your header data.

Comment: Ah, yep.  Didnt look closely enough at the docs, that's precisely what I wanted and works the same as the approach I mentioned in my answer.   This is definitely the right way to go, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are using a length field frame decoder it should be first in the pipeline unless you are also using SSL or compression handlers which will go before your frame handler. The easiest solution is just to put your protocol id handler after the frame handler instead of before.

Comment: I take your point, and while that might work in a single protocol setup, that will fail when I include something based on the PortUnification example Netty provides.  Then there's no way to tell if the first N bytes are the frame size or the protocol identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` is roughly what you want in this situation, but it does not handle the delimiter being the front of the frame rather than the end, so if you use it in this case, it will basically eat your traffic.

Using the `indexOf` method from `DelimitedBasedFrameDecoder` you can put together a very simple decoder to use on a server channel that will split incoming traffic by the delimiter sequence while eating the delimiter:

```
public static final class DelimitingProtocolDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    private final ByteBuf mDelimiter;

    public DelimitingProtocolDecoder(final ByteBuf theDelimiter) {
        mDelimiter = theDelimiter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(final ChannelHandlerContext theContext, final ByteBuf theInput, final List<Object> theOutput) throws Exception {
        int aIndex = indexOf(theInput, mDelimiter);

        while (aIndex != -1) {
            if (aIndex > 0) {
                ByteBuf aBuffer = theContext.alloc().buffer(aIndex, aIndex);

                theInput.readBytes(aBuffer);

                theOutput.add(aBuffer);
            }

            theInput.skipBytes(mDelimiter.capacity());

            aIndex = indexOf(theInput, mDelimiter);
        }

        theOutput.add(theInput.readBytes(theInput.readableBytes()));
    }
}
```